# Allowing the Javascript Onbeforeunload Function on the specific button on ASP.NET Framework

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, c#-4.0

How to set the Onbeforeunload Function on the specific button?
Example, I have 3 buttons.

```
<div>
   <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="Back" CssClass="po-font" Height="30px"/>
   <asp:Button ID="btnSumbit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="po-font" Height="30px"/>
   <asp:Button ID="btnSaveToDraft" runat="server" Text="Save To Draft" CssClass="po-font" Height="30px"/>
</div>
```

On javascript, I did something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
   return "Are you sure you want to leave this page? Any unsaved progress will be  lost";
  }
</script>
```

The function will work properly though but I want to specify the function in an specific button probably on the "Back" button. I did something like.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave this page? Any unsaved progress will be  lost";
  }

$('#btnBack').live('click', function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
});

</script>
```

but Id doesn't work. How to do this? Any Ideas? I just want to trigger the function on the specified button. Help me.

Comment: How doesn't it work?

Comment: I just want to apply the function on "Back" button. Not on the two buttons(btnSumbit,btnSaveToDraft). I used the syntax above but it doesn't work. Or should I use much better function?

Answer (score 0):

First off its unlikely that the ID is correct as ASP.NET prefixes the ID with the containers if that object. Either give `btnBack` a class and use that or:

```
$("[id$='btnBack']").on("click",...)
```

I'll edit with a battle tested version when I'm back in front of my pc

*** Edit to add battle tested code ***

So you need to bind the unload event to the `window`, you can't assign a function to it as Kevin says in his answer. If you only want it to fire for a specific button, the code below is something I use in active production (it has a few more checks, and checks if anything has been changed on a page before firing etc...), so should work for you:

```
if (self == top) { // Check we're not in an iFrame or colorbox
   $(window).bind("beforeunload", function (event) { // bind the window unload event
        if (backLinkClicked) { // Check if the back link has been clicked, if so prompt
            return "Are you sure you want to leave this page? Any unsaved progress will be  lost";
        };
    });
}
```

Then your `click` handler:

```
var backLinkClicked = false;
$("[id$='btnBack']").click(function() { backLinkClicked = true });
```

So you back button click handler just changes the variable to fire the prompt on unload.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('<%=btnBack.ClientID%>').click(function(){...});` because asp.net prefix its own client with the control id and html rendered id may look like ct100$btnBack.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should understand that *onbeforeunload* is an event, and by putting:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
```

you are attaching an event handler to *window*, which will be global.

If I am correct, what you want is bringing up a confirmation dialog when user tries to navigate away by clicking on a button. I suggest you try this:

```
$('#<%=btnBack.ClientID%>').on('click', function (e) {
    // check if user clicked cancel
    if (!confirm("Are you sure [...]") {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

With this, when user clicks the button, a confirmation dialog will appear (*[confirm()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)*). If user clicks *cancel*, code will call *[stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)* (which should prevent other JS event handler from running) and *[preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)* (which disable the default action when the button is clicked, e.g., submitting the form).

I haven't tested this out myself, but I guess it should work.